# Why bash puts process started via '&' to foreground?

Tags: bash, job-control

When a process is started with "&",
bash places the new process to foreground group for a short time
and then places
itself back to foreground group.

As far as I know, when we run any external 
command without the "&" background operator, the shell creates a
new process group for the command and notifies the terminal that this process group is now
in the foreground. When we run with "&", foreground process group MUST NOT change.

I used a C program on linux which just prints foreground process group and 
own process group on start and then prints the same after a sleep.

I get the following results:

```
tcgetpgrp=19981 getpgrp=19981
sleep(5)
tcgetpgrp=11996 getpgrp=19981
```

In this example 11996 is the pid of bash.

I only noticed this behavior when run as `(./test&)` and under heavy load (never as `./test&`).

Is bash behaving the right way?

Bash version: 4.4.12

**EDIT**

Added pid value as suggested by @Costi:

```
tcgetpgrp=29148 getpgrp=29148 getpid=29149
sleep
tcgetpgrp=28566 getpgrp=29148 getpid=29149
```

28566 is pid of bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(...)` creates a subshell in bash. As per bash manual:

> (list) list  is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below)

My guess is you are seeing the PID of that subshell as the foreground process, **not** the PID of your `test` command. And the subshell exits quite quickly (right after firing your command in background).

To validate this, add the value returned by `getpid` to the mix and check if that is the same as your `getpgrp` value when run in a subshell.

Comment: You were right - see **EDIT** in OP. I use parentheses to prevent job control messages from being printed to the terminal. In my program I use `tcgetpgrp`+`getpgrp` as a way to debug: say `prog` - and all messages will go to terminal directly without the need to open log file; for normal operation say `prog&` and all messages will go to log file. The fix of problem in OP is to change `getpgrp` into `getpid`.